# TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    def sort_shit(self, arr):
        if len(arr) == 1:
            yield arr
        else:
            mid = int(len(arr) / 2)
            l = self.sort_shit(arr[:mid])
            r = self.sort_shit(arr[mid:])
        i = j = 0
        result = []
        while i < len(l) and j < len(r):
            if l[i] < r[j]:
                result.append(l[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                result.append(r[j])
                j += 1
        result += l[i:]
        result += r[j:]
        yield result
```

Вывод ошибки `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: Всё правильно, у генераторов длины нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и написали в комментарии - у генератора нет длины. Если копнуть глубже, нужно понимать что такое генератор

> Генераторы являются простым средством для создания итераторов.
>
> Итератор - тип, позволяющий реализовать поток данных и предлагающий средства для продвижения по нему.
>
> http://pythonz.net/references/named/generator/

Получается что функция-генератор возвращает итератор. Чтобы остановить движение по итератору необходимо исключение **StopIteration**. Из этого следует, что для того, чтобы получить все элементы итератора, и узнать его длину, необходимо полностью по нему пройтись.

Тут есть два варианта:

1. Запомнить все элементы итератора - `len(list(arr))`
2. Пересмотреть свой код, и понять что метод-генератор тут особо и не нужен

Answer (score 0):

У вас опечатка вконце:

```
yield result
```

а надо:

```
return result
```

Comment: Да и в начале тоже тогда

Comment: Это не опечатка...Просто мне нужно чтобы функция вернула генератор